# Getting error "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider"

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, ignite, java-17

While running unit tests for my Springboot application, I am getting below error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider: Provider org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider could not be instantiated
  at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:586)
  at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:813)
  at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:729)
  at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1403)
  at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry$1.run(Caching.java:448)
  at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry$1.run(Caching.java:442)
  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
  at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProviders(Caching.java:442)
  at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProviders(Caching.java:410)
  at javax.cache.Caching.getCachingProviders(Caching.java:187)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$JCacheProviderAvailableCondition.getMatchOutcome(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:160)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.getConditionOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:195)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:189)
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.lambda$getMatchOutcomes$0(AbstractNestedCondition.java:169)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
  at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
  at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
  at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider
  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor115.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
  at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:789)
  ... 128 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError [in thread "Test worker"]
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.<clinit>(IgniteUtils.java:888)
  at org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider.<clinit>(CachingProvider.java:53)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
  ... 132 more
```

I am using Java 17, Springboot 3.0.3 and ignite 2.14.0

Tried adding below to build.gradle but still getting same error

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api
testImplementation group: 'javax.cache', name: 'cache-api', version: '1.1.1'
```

I would really appreciate any help here. Let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at [https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java)?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, it was working properly using Java 8 and Java 11

Comment: I guess that it was some lack of support for java 17, Ignite 2.15 was released recently I guess it should has better java 17 support, give it a try.